# How to display search results in groups like whatsapp does

Tags: search, whatsapp

I have a viewpager with some tabs. I always use the same fragment with a listview to load some String data into the listview. So far, so good. I now want to implement a searchview. And, I want to group the search results like whatsapp does. So the found listview items should be grouped by the tabs they were found in. 
My question is: Which view does whatsapp use and how can I do so ? 
Can I keep my simple listview or do I need some other stuff ? I thought about an expandable Listview, could this be a solution ? 
Unfortunately, SO doesn't allow me to post an WA screenshot at this moment. But I think you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of this day, I can say that my desired Grouping of Searchresults is definitely possible with an Expandable Listview.
You can hide the Group indicator and disable collapse so it looks like in whatsapp.

Comment: I now think whatsapp uses a RecyclerView with different view types.